# Virtualization enabled but it says not enabled

Tags: android-studio, intel, virtualization

I am trying to install Android Studio but it says that it can't install Intel vt-x. I downloaded Intel vt-x but during installation it said that my computer meets the requirements but virtualization is not enabled.
I checked the bios and there, virtualization was enabled. 
I checked for other ways how to fix this, but I can't find anything. Can someone tell me what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Intel vt-x is a feature of your processor; it is not a software library.

You need to reboot into your BIOS and then select to enable VT-X support. If the option doesn't exist, then your processor does not support it.

If you are installing this inside a virtual machine, then you need to enable detection of hardware flags (such as vt-x) on the guest. Depending on how you are running the vm, the options will vary.

Comment: I found a tutorial about it and they changed the Virtualizations option in the bios to enabled.
When I opened the bios, the Virtualization option was already Enabled.